# Change microdata itemprop name value with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-plus

Here is the code that fails:

```
var newName= "jill"
$("h1").attr('itemprop','name').html(newName);
```

Here is the microdata:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">

<div style="display:none;"> 
<h1 itemprop="name">jack</h1>
<img itemprop="image" src="http://somehewhere.com/something.png" />
<p itemprop="description">some text</p>

</div>
```

I need to change the value of "jack" to "jill".

I'm changing it for use with G+ since the var value of "jill" (although static in this example) will change since it is dynamic.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: **Does anyone know if changing microdata with any method is possible?**

The method below and my original method both show success in the console log. But, neither change the original values when tested with Google's Structured Data Testing Tool or with G+ share button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the value with jQuery as Adil showed, but that doesn't solve your issue. Google+ takes a snapshot of the HTML to decide how to create the snippet either before your javascript runs or doesn't execute the javascript at all.

You're better off making the page dynamic by using a server-side language.

Maybe with some more explanation about your situation, we can suggest another approach or workaround?

Comment: Thanks. I was suspecting something like this was the case. Unfortunately, I can only get the var value on the client-side.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/QR7vh/)**

```
$("h1[itemprop=name]").html(newName)
```

Comment: The second one reports the change in my console log (as did my original) but it does not update when tested with Google's Structured Data Testing Tool.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, although the approach is different, I was getting successful results with mine too. Problem is that it fails in Google's Structured Data Testing Tool and with a G+ share test. The name remains "jack" although the console.log and our tests report differently. Yikes!

Comment: How you are getting results in Google's Structured Data Testing Tool? Can you show me the script you used ?

Comment: [Here:] (http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?) Sorry, I cannot expose the failing page.